# Daily S&P500 close in JSON?

Tags: market-data, historical-data

Does anyone know of a publicly available dataset for S&P500 index published daily in json format?

Took a look at [quandl](https://www.quandl.com/) but nothing for free. Google searches bring back a whole host of unhelpful sponsored ads, old data or monthly publications.

Comment: Why not just pull it down in csv and parse into JSON?

Comment: Trying to keep things efficient - think thats gonna be the way forward. Or the S&P ETF prices in Json..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the Bloomberg API:
https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/chart/data/1D/SPX:IND

I hope it's what you're looking for.

Comment: This looks close! I'm looking for the last year of close values though. How did you navigate to the API - I find the SPX:IND quote at the below link and don't see the option? https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND

Comment: You can find the logic behind this explained here: https://github.com/matthewfieger/bloomberg_stock_data

Comment: Sadly it appears Bloomberg blocks traffic to this endpoint from AWS ip addresses. I have not found a good alternative for scripts running there.